# Contra variance with interfaces

Tags: c#-4.0, generics

I have an interface iExportColumn  and a class  ExportColumn   implementing the interfce. ExportColumnCollection  class should be generic for all the classes that implements IExportColumn interface.

```
public interface IExportColumn
{
    string Header { get; set; }
    string ColumnName { get; set; }
}

public class ExportColumn : IExportColumn
{
    public ExportColumn(){}
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
}

public class ExportColumnCollection<T> where T: IExportColumn
{
    private List<T> cols;

    public ExportColumnCollection (List<T> c)
    {
        cols = c;
    }

    public T Columninfo (string colname)
    {
    }
      .....
 }
```

I am getting run time error saying could not load type `ExportColumnCollection`.

I am looking for something to achieve somthing like 
`List<IExportColumn> = new List<ExportColumn>();`

I have two classes implementing the interfaces IExportColumn and I need to hold a GenericCollection to handle List

Comment: Why are you not using `List<T>` within `ExportColumnCollection`? That seems the simplest approach...

Comment: Thats my mistake.. I am using the below  public class ExportColumnCollection<T> where T: IExportColumn { private List<T> cols; public ExportColumnCollection (List<T> c) { cols = c; } public T Columninfo (string colname) { } ..... }

Comment: Writing code in comments isn't generally useful - especially when you've provided no text to explain why you're doing so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper usage for your class would be:

```
List<IExportColumn> list= new List<IExportColumn>();
// you may add to the collection any class which implements IExportColumn
list.Add(new ExportColumn1() { ColumnName = "Id" });
list.Add(new ExportColumn2() { ColumnName = "Value" });

ExportColumnCollection<IExportColumn> collection = new 
    ExportColumnCollection<IExportColumn>(list);
var colInfo = collection.ColumnInfo("Id");
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a issue with the assembly due to reference, which made me to explore some other options.. but now all sorted out .. thanks